# multiCapabilities function throwing error in protractor

Tags: node.js, automation, automated-tests, protractor

I need to run my tests in chrome,FF and IE. When I use following tag in TC3conf.js file my execution works fine.

```
capabilities: 
  {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
```

However when I use following tag, protractor throws an error.

```
var Reporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var path = require('path');
exports.config = {
   allScriptsTimeout: 99999,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  maxSessions: 1,

 multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}, {
  'browserName': 'firefox'
}],
  framework: 'jasmine',

 specs: ['TC_2.js'],

 onPrepare: function() {  
      beforeEach(function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
    });  

      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
         baseDirectory: 'D:/TestReport3/',
         docTitle: 'Execution Details',
         docName: 'Report.html',

  metaDataBuilder: function(spec, descriptions, results, capabilities){
            var metaData = {
                description: descriptions.join('|'),
                 passed: results.passed(),          
                 browser: {
                  name: capabilities.caps_.browserName
                  , version: capabilities.caps_.version
                }

              };

            if(results.items_.length > 0) {
              var result = results.items_[0];
             metaData.message = result.message;                    
               metaData.trace = result.trace.stack;                         
            }           

            return metaData;
         } 

      }));
   },
};
```

**ERROR - failed loading configuration file TC3conf.js**

Could you please tell me the solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide us with some more details? 1. The version of protractor and selenium 2. The operating system you are running protractor on 3. The version of node/io you are using?

Comment: @NickTomlin  Hi..Following are my details.

Protractor version- 2.1.0
OS version-Windows 7
Selenium server standalone driver version-2.44.0
Node Js Version: 0.12.7

Comment: Can you share the full contents of your configuration file, and the exact command you are invoking protractor with?

Comment: @NickTomlin. Find my code below.

var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
var path = require('path');

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

maxSessions: 1,

 capabilities: {
  
    'browserName': 'firefox',
  
  },
  framework: 'jasmine',

specs: ['TC_2.js',],

onPrepare: function() {   
      beforeEach(function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
    });  
metaDataBuilder: function(spec, descriptions, results, capabilities){
}

Comment: The code you posted in the comment is not valid JavaScript (perhaps something got lost when adding it as a comment). Could you update your original post with the formatted configuration code?

Comment: @NickTomlin Updated code in my original post.Could you please review and let me know?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the configuration error using the conf file you gave above. Can you also list the exact command you are using to launch protractor?  I am also on OSX, so perhaps this is a windows issue

Comment: Following are comments I am using:
1.cd C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm
2.webdriver-manager start

**Next command window**
1.cd C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm
2.protractor TC_2.js

Comment: @NickTomlin. I think it might be a problem with selenium standalone driver.I have updated the driver into 2.47.1 and multiCapabilities function working fine in IE,FF and chrome.Hence closing the issue.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be a problem with selenium standalone server driver.I have updated the driver into 2.47.1 and multiCapabilities function working fine in IE,FF and chrome in protractor.Hence closing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem but I believe you have an un-needed comma and un-needed quotes

try changing

```
 capabilities: {

    'browserName': 'firefox',

  },
```

to this

```
 capabilities: {

    browserName: 'firefox'

  },
```

Comment: Updated code in my original post.Could you please review and let me know?

Comment: have you tried removing the html reporter to see if there is some kind of conflict with it and using multi capabilities.

Comment: Where I need to remove html reporter?

Config.js file or inside nodemodules?

Comment: just for troubleshooting remove/comment the code for the html reporter within the confi.js file. That way you can see if for some reason that plugin is causing the issue when you use multi capabilities.